# Specifically, how does Reactjs retrieve data from firebase function triggers?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, express, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am using express to create my firebase functions, and I understand how to create regular callable functions. I am lost however on the exact way to implement trigger functions for the background (i.e. onCreate, onDelete, onUpdate, onWrite), as well as how Reactjs in the frontend is supposed to receive the data.

The scenario I have is a generic chat system that uses react, firebase functions with express and realtime database. I am generally confused on the process of using triggers for when someone sends a message, to update another user's frontend data.

I have had a hard time finding a tutorial or documentation on the combination of these questions. Any links or a basic programmatic examples of the life cycle would be wonderful.

The parts I do understand is the way to write a trigger function:

```
exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/original')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
      // Only edit data when it is first created.
      if (change.before.exists()) {
        return null;
      }
      // Exit when the data is deleted.
      if (!change.after.exists()) {
        return null;
      }
      // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
      const original = change.after.val();
      console.log('Uppercasing', context.params.pushId, original);
      const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();
      // You must return a Promise when performing asynchronous tasks inside a Functions such as
      // writing to the Firebase Realtime Database.
      // Setting an "uppercase" sibling in the Realtime Database returns a Promise.
      return change.after.ref.parent.child('uppercase').set(uppercase);
    });
```

But I don't understand how this is being called or how the data from this reaches frontend code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background functions cannot return anything to client. They run after a certain event i.e. `onWrite()` in this case. If you want to update data at `/messages/{pushId}/original` to other users then you'll have to use [Firebase Client SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#web_value_events) to listen to that path:

```
import { getDatabase, ref, onValue} from "firebase/database";

const db = getDatabase();
const msgRef = ref(db, `/messages/${pushId}/original`);

onValue(msgRef, (snapshot) => {
  const data = snapshot.val();
  console.log(data)
});
```

You can also listen to `/messages/${pushId}` with [`onChildAdded()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_child_events) to get notified about any new node under that path.